# Show that if $c$ is a positive constant, then $\frac{1}{c}F(\frac{s}{c})=\mathcal{L}\{f(ct)\}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory

Suppose that $F(s)=\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}$ (Defined as the usual Laplacian
operator).

> Show that if $c$ is a positive constant, then
>   $\frac{1}{c}F(\frac{s}{c})=\mathcal{L}\{f(ct)\}$.

$$\mathcal{L}\{f(ct)\}=\int^{\infty}_{0} e^{-sct}f(ct) dt = \lim_{A \to \infty} \int^{A}_{0} e^{-sct}f(ct) dt$$ and

$$\int^{A}_{0} e^{-sct}f(ct) dt =\frac{1}{c} \int^{cA}_{0} e^{-st}f(t) dt.$$

I am stuck at this point. Is there anyone who could help me at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't written the Laplace transform correctly in several ways: Notice that the left depends on $f$ while the integrals do not. Furthermore, the kernel is $e^{-st}$, not $e^{-sct}$.

But once you have

$$\mathcal{L}\left\{f(ct)\right\} = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-st} f(ct) \, dt$$

Now make the change of variables $u = ct$ to rewrite this as

$$\frac 1 c \int_0^{\infty} e^{-su/c} f(u) \, du = \frac 1 c F\left(\frac s c\right)$$
as desired. Make this rigorous in terms of limits and the improper integral, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful: the definition of the Laplace transform is

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}\{f(t) \} = \int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}dt,
\end{equation}

so when you substitute $ct$ in, the $e^{-st}$ factor needs to remain as is.

Comment: I know all that. I have modified my question in the same time you displayed your question. Sorry

Comment: That's ok. There is a complete answer to your question above!